# calculate div width in pixel according to content for horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one parent div with some static width. On a button click I have to add some child div to that parent.

I have to provide one horizontal scroll if the total width of the child div exceeds the parent width.
But the main problem is, I can't set a static width to child div.
It have to come according with the string(content) of that particular div.

I want to display the content in single line only.

```
1234 56789 111 111 1111 1111111 11 111111 11111111111 - div 1 content

2223333 - div 2 content

2222 333 222 2 33 44 33333 -div 3 content
```

Like unlimited child div will come. If there is any way to find the width of the div according to the length(including space)of the content.
If it is possible then I can set the width of each child div.

I added one fiddle but that is not perfect.

```
<div class="wrap-poltrona">
<div class="poltrona">jndjjwnjwq</div>
<div class="poltrona">jndjwdjnwqjd</div>
<div class="poltrona">nd nwdwednwedwendewjdwejdewdenewdjwenejwjnedjewjdewjdewdjewdwjjdwjejw</div>
<div class="poltrona"></div>
<div class="poltrona"></div>
<div class="poltrona"></div>
<div class="poltrona"></div>
<div class="poltrona"></div>
<div class="poltrona"></div>
<div class="poltrona"></div>
<div class="poltrona"></div>
<div class="poltrona"></div>
<div class="poltrona"></div>
<div class="poltrona"></div>
<div class="poltrona"></div>
<div class="poltrona"></div>
<div class="poltrona"></div>
<div class="poltrona"></div>
```

[**CODE**](http://jsfiddle.net/renjithgovind/sykofvkL/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the number of inner `<div>`s and divide the wrap's width by that. Then set the inner ones to the calculated width.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var p = $(".wrap-poltrona > .poltrona");
  var cs = getComputedStyle(p.get(0));
  var m = parseInt(cs.marginLeft) + parseInt(cs.marginRight);
  var w = $(".wrap-poltrona").width() / p.length;
  p.width(w - m * 1.01);
});
```

```css
.wrap-poltrona {
  width: 500px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green
}
.poltrona {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  // display:inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-poltrona">
  <div class="poltrona">jnd</div>
  <div class="poltrona">jn</div>
  <div class="poltrona">nd n</div>
  <div class="poltrona"></div>
  <div class="poltrona"></div>
  <div class="poltrona"></div>
  <div class="poltrona"></div>
  <div class="poltrona"></div>
  <div class="poltrona"></div>
  <div class="poltrona"></div>
  <div class="poltrona"></div>
  <div class="poltrona"></div>
  <div class="poltrona"></div>
  <div class="poltrona"></div>
  <div class="poltrona"></div>
  <div class="poltrona"></div>
  <div class="poltrona"></div>
  <div class="poltrona">end</div>
</div>
```

I used a factor of 1.01 to slightly decrease the width in case the last inner div disappears due to rounding.

Comment: can u provide one fiddler or can u edit that link which i provided in the question